# How to support a floating deck stair

Tags: deck

I am working on building a floating deck and am having trouble deciding on how to support my stairs. I was planning on having a single step, and was wondering what the options were as to what it could sit on. Ideally I would want it to look like the deck stair is sitting on grass.

From my research the following may work:

Concrete base (strong, but a lot of work to mold/pour)

- pavers (layers: dirt, landscape fabric, paver base, paver sand,
  pavers)
- gravel/paver base ? (layers: dirt, landscape fabric, gravel)
- dirt ? (layers: dirt, landscape fabric) (wood is pressure treated ground contact rated, but heard it will rot eventually), seen a lot
  of videos where people do this, but it doesn't feel right.
- other? dig posts?

Here are some pictures of the current state of my deck, and the stair design.

Note that I live in southern California so I do not have to worry about frost.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPkG6.jpg

Thanks